# Freeze Z Rotation programmatically - Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the Unity inspector (v5+), you have a "Freeze Z" rotation, any idea which is the equivalent in code? The idea is to enable/disable Z rotation of a 2D object due a certain condition by C# code.

Answer (score 6):

You want to set the [Rigidbody.constraints](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html) to a [`RigidbodyConstraint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html):

```
transform.rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
```

The `RigidbodyConstraint` constants can be combined with the `|` operator:

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY;
```

Comment: Nice! I end up using 
rig2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;

as it is a 2d rigid body, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To put this as an answer for 2D, use the following:

```
Rigidbody2D body2d;

void Awake() {

    body2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

}

void Update () {

    // on this line, calculate condition for freezing rotation

    if (condition) {

        body2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;

    } else {

        body2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;

    }

}
```